# how to connect an ios device to a Hotspot driven by hostapd

Tags: ios, wifi

I met a problem to connect an ios device to the hotspot driven by hostapd which runs on my arm board.

IOS device will take a long time to connect, at last, the wifi signal is shown on status bar, and also got the ip address, but the circle, by the ssid side, won't disappear, it always turns round. This will make user think that the wifi doesn't connected yet, but it really connected.

I have tried some devices to connect the hotsopt, such as android cell phones, windows laptop, they all work correctly.

PS. My English is not good, I hope you could understand what I mean.

Answer (score 0):

if the "circle by the ssid side" keeps showing ，i think your device is still trying to get ip address.
could you please provide us with more detail messages? such as your hostapd configure file and your dhcpd configure file.